# In a topology space, a set is open iff the complement is closed?

Tags: general-topology

I am learning topology spaces and in the notes it states a theorem:

> For a topology space $(X,\tau)$, and $A\subseteq X$, $A$ is closed iff $X\setminus A$ is open.

In the notes, the definition of topology is that it should follow the following three rules:

> 1. The empty set and the whole set should be in the topology.
> 2. Finite, countable, and uncountable union of elements in the topology is still in the topology.
> 3. Finite intersection of elements in the topology is still in the topology

And in the notes it says that the proof of this theorem is similar for that of metric space, but we don't have distance in metric space, so we cannot order all set of open sets containing $x$ to get a limit and have a contradiction. I have the proof for cases if $\tau$ is finite and countable, how to prove the uncountable case?

Also, in the notes, the definition of closed set is that any limit of any convergent sequence is still in the set, so I need to prove this definition is equivalent to what the theorem states.

Comment: I n a topological space a closed set is **defined** as a set whose complement is open. Do you have a different definition?

Comment: This does not make sense. What you wrote is the (standard) definition of topology, not some theorem. Maybe you got things mixed up and they want you to prove that the open sets as introduced in your metric space class form a topology?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prove it, since that's not a theorem. It's a *definition* instead. That is how we *define* a closed set in a topological space.

Comment: I think you mean "that's how we define a closed set".

Comment: @bubba I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to define closed sets in the context of metric spaces is given below.

**Definitions**

Let $(X,d_{X})$ be a metric space.

We say that $E\subseteq X$ is closed iff $E\supseteq\partial E$, where $\partial E$ indicates the boundary of $E$.

Moreover, we also say that $E\subseteq X$ is open iff $E\cap\partial E = \varnothing$.

**Proposition**

The set $E\subseteq X$ is closed iff $E^{c}$ is open.

**Proof**

Based on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3960065/is-it-correct-to-define-operatornamecl-omega-omega-cup-partial-omega/3960102#3960102) answer, we are going to prove the proposed claim.

In order to do so, we shall consider the implication $(\Rightarrow)$ first.

If $E$ is closed (which means that $E = \overline{E} = \text{int}(E)\cup\partial E$), then we have that
\begin{align*}
E^{c} & = X - \text{int}(E)\cup\partial E = \text{ext}(E) = \text{int}(E^{c}) 
\end{align*}

from which we conclude that $E^{c}$ is open.

Conversely, let us prove the converse implication $(\Leftarrow)$.

If $E^{c}$ is open, then we have that

\begin{align*}
E^{c}\cap\partial E^{c} = \varnothing & \Longleftrightarrow E^{c}\cap\partial E = \varnothing\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \partial E\subseteq E
\end{align*}

whence we conclude that $E$ is closed.

Hopefully this helps!